# Additive functors preserving epimorphisms

Tags: category-theory

I have a functor $F : Mod_A \rightarrow Mod_B $ which is additive, preserves direct sums and quotients. Does it preserves epimorphisms ? I think we just need to show that it is right exact.

Comment: Something like, $f : M \rightarrow N $ epi so $N \cong  M / Ker f$. Then, $FN=F(M/Ker f)=FM/ F(Ker f)= FM / Ker Ff$. But not sure...

Answer (score 2):

If $F$ preserves quotients, then it preserves cokernels.
But in an abelian category, such as modules over a ring, epimorphisms are cokernels, thus they are preserved as well.

Comment: In an abelian category, it's the codomain of a cokernel.